# Problems installing sails with long wait getting registry

Tags: node.js, npm, sails.js

I tried installing sails through the command: `npm install sails -g`. However, the console seems to be waiting indefinitely fetching the Metadata from this directory. Is there any way I could resolve this?

```
[    ..............] / fetchMetadata: sill mapToRegistry uri https://registry.npmjs.org/uid-safe
```

Comment: Installing sails.js sometimes takes too long, and it's normal and mentioned in sails documentations either.

Comment: it has been 4 hours and it's still stuck at the same progress

Comment: May be due to internet connectivity issue?

Comment: I could access the link from the browser but still having the same issue while installing from the command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

try two things:

1. reset npm registry: `npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org`
2. install sails with admin rights: `sudo npm install sails -g`